# How to 'form' a term for the citizens of a city?

Tags: word-request

> If it's New York, then it's New Yorker 
>  If it's London, then it's Londoner, and so on...

In India, it's Mumbaikar for Mumbai but Delhiite for Delhi. In short, difficult to guess! Some times such terms take 'ker,' some times, 'ner..' and so on.

But how do I form such words if I have no time to search on the Internet? Say, while explaining about the habit of people from a particular city.

Is there any rule? Or at least a trick?

What about Amsterdam? Sydney? Tokyo? Shanghai? The list is endless!

Answer (score 3):

There is no standard rule for this. Most cities have a name that is used for the residents of that city, but many small towns have no official designation. You will also sometimes find that one location may have more than one name for its residents. I used to live in Adelaide, and I have heard locals refer to themselves as Adeladians, Adelonians and Adelites.

For the records the correct term for the name given to people from a particular country, region, state, city, etc., is Demonym. The following link will give you the Demonyms for many countries, cities, etc., but I doubt that it is complete. [Demonyms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demonym#Cities)

Comment: Wow. I did not know the Adelaide thing. +1 for that and of course for the term

Comment: @Maulik V   I believe that the 'official' name is Adelaideans, which I have not seen used often. However, as I assume it is pronounced the same as Adelaidian, it is possible that I have heard it more than I have seen it.

Answer (score 2):

There are no rules, any more than there are for any other kind of names. Every locale has its own demonyms— countries, continents, regions, subregions, cities, towns, districts, neighborhoods— and you have to look them up individually as there are dozens of patterns, and the preferred one may not be obvious — residents of Los Angeles are *Angelenos* (whether male or female), but folks from San Diego are simply *San Diegans*. Furthermore, it is entirely possible for two cities with the same name to prefer different words for their residents, or for the adjectives thereof.

Wikipedia includes numerous lists, linked from https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demonym.

Comment: I live in Bristol, but I'll never be a Bristolian because I wasn't born here.